# PHP - take an image from file directory and upload it to SQL database

Tags: php, file, pdo

I am creating a signup page for my website and I wanted to set the users profile picture as a **default** one for now until the user is ready to change. I know how to get the filename of the picture using an array and `new DirectoryIterator` but the problem is i want to upload the `blob` type into the database as well so when they want to change it, i can change both and not just the file name. I tried using

```
file_get_contents();
```

but it wasn't working and i got an error like

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(default-user-profilepic.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\MT\infoupdate.php on line 128
```

So what i want to do is, take a file from my file directory and upload it with the filename and file_tmp into the database. Here is my code

PHP

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    //Set variables
    $fullname = trim($_POST['fullname']);
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $storePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
    $cpassword = trim($_POST['cpassword']);
    $boolean = true;

    //Check if values are empty
    if(!empty($fullname) && !empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($cpassword) && !empty($_POST['gender'])){

        //Check if email is valid
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){

            die ("Email is Not Valid!");
        }
        //Check if passwrod is greater 6
        if(strlen($password) < 6 && strlen($cpassword) < 6){

            die ("Password has to be GREATER than 6 characters!");

        }

        //Check if password has atleast ONE Uppercase, One Lowercase and a number
        if(!preg_match("(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$)",$password)){

                echo 'Password needs to be at least ONE uppercase, ONE lowercase, and a number!';
                exit;
            }

        //Check if passwords match
        if(!password_verify($cpassword, $storePassword)){

            die ("Passwords DO NOT Match!");
        }

        try{

        // new php data object
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception 
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }

        //Check if username is in DB
        $stmtUsername = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");

        $stmtUsername->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

        if($resultUsername = $stmtUsername->fetch()){

            die("Username is already in user! Please try a different one!");
        }

        $userid = $resultUsername['user_id'];
        //Check if EMAIL is in DB
        $stmtEmail = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");

        $stmtEmail->execute(array(':email'=>$email));

        if($resultEmail = $stmtEmail->fetch()){

                die("Email already in use! Please try a different one!");
            }

        $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');

        // init result

        // directory to scan
        $directory = new DirectoryIterator('images');

        // iterate
        foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
            // must be a file
            if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
                // file extension
                $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                // check if extension match
                if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
                    // add to result
                    $file_name = $fileinfo->getFilename();
                }
            }
        }

        $isDev = 1;
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        //set up sql
        $query = "INSERT INTO generalusersdata(fullname, username, email, password, profile_image, isDev, gender)VALUES(:fullname, :username, :email, :storePassword, :file_name, :isDev, :gender)";

        $stmt = $handler->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':storePassword', $storePassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':isDev', $isDev, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if(!$stmt->execute()){

             $_SESSION['error'] = true;
             header("Location: errorsignup.php");
             exit;

        }

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        setcookie("username", $username, time() + 60*60*24*365);
        header("Location: developerUpload.php");

    //Empty else    
    }else{

        echo "Missing Values!";
        exit;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: "_but it wasn't working and i got a lot of errors._" Can you please, share the errors with us?

Comment: Uuhm sorry but why are you looping through the images directory? I don't understand. You always endup with the last file because there is no break after setting $file_name.

Comment: And why storing it as blob while you have it on disk? Another part that is weird to me.

Comment: Thats how i learned it honestly. I want to put it in the "longblob" type on the SQL database @DigitalHuman

Comment: Hi @Jagr, meh. Don't do it. Unless there is no other way. Restoring a backup with images as blobs in DB's is a nightmare. Same for performance. Big tables (blob fields) don't fit in memory easily. Just keep file as files and leave them on the disk ;)

Comment: Wait what if the user wants to upload a picture later one? idk if SQL will let me put a place holder in the picture slot.

Comment: You just have a path issue. Correct your path in `file_get_contents()`;

Comment: Well should i put "MT/filename.png"? or start from the "C: drive"

Comment: The problem can probably be solved by using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: absolute paths? Can you be more descriptive :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you have a set of images in a folder named images. Every user will receive a default profile picture. If they want to change their picture they choose another from that folder. If that is correct, you won't need to upload them as a blob. Here is a way you can do it:

1. You will store just the filename in your user table
2. For new users you'll store the default picture's filename In your view, i.e.:
   profile summary, you will use the img-tag and put the picture file
   name as a source.
3. When he changes his profile picture you will update just the filename in the database.

Maybe that process above is an option for you.

Your code is producing your warning

```
Warning: file_get_contents(default-user-profilepic.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\MT\infoupdate.php on line 128
```

because the file path is not correct. You are working with a relative path, that means your current path is your infoupdate.php. It tries to find the requested file in the MIT folder. Since I don't know your directory structure, I can not provide a better description. If your Image folder is inside the MIT folder, you can try to change your Directory Iterator line to:

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('/images');
```

or use absolute path instead:

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('C:\wamp64\www\MT\images');
```

Comment: Well all the user will update from a file they have, i just needed the picture to upload as their default profile picture for now. Thanks for the help because i used the "absolute path" and it worked :D

Comment: Hello MuratBa, my computer shut down on me earlier and all my unsaved code for this question was deleted. But the only thing i lost was the "directoryIterator" part but the problem is i can't remember how to submit the file, or image, from the "$directory" into the database as a "longblob". Can you help?